# How to properly use LIKE statement in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have database which contains a field named groupid and group name.

sample data

```
groupid   groupname
123          abc
234          bcr
1237         cde
```

I like to compare groupid with another inputted data, its size is greater than size of group id.

I tried a query that not return correct answer

```
SELECT * 
  FROM mydata
 WHERE groupid LIKE '12309098';
```

My expected answer is `abc`

What are the changes to made for correct answer

thanks in advance

Comment: you need to use % with like %at end for starts with and %at start for ends with, and on both sides for contains

Comment: `LIKE` isn't some magic statetment that will recognize patterns.It can look for strings. `LIKE '123%'` would return the first group, but also the third.

Comment: I dont think LIKE would work in your case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you want the value in the row to be the prefix of your input and not the other way around, you can just turn `LIKE` around the other way;

```
SELECT * 
FROM mydata
WHERE '12309098' LIKE CONCAT(groupid, '%');
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d77fd/1);

EDIT: Since you asked about SQLite, there you need to use `||` for concatenation;

```
SELECT * 
FROM mydata 
WHERE '12309098' LIKE `groupid` || '%';
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b480d/1).

Comment: @Rex It concatenates the row value `123` with `%` to form `123%`, which is a like-pattern that matches `12309098` as a prefix.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson but wont it give abc and cde both as result

Comment: `1237%` won't match `12309098`. `1230%` would have though.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ok understood, this matches groupids with 12309098, thanks :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Wonderful and Clever Solution,  Thanks.  I have a doubt is this solution works with sqlite ?

Comment: @Krishna Updated the answer with SQLite syntax.

Answer (score 6):

You could do like below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my data
WHERE '12309098' LIKE CONCAT('%', groupid, '%');
```

Comment: @Rex It is used to concat strings.

Comment: @Rex It appends `%` before and after the `groupID`

Comment: @xdazz but wont it give abc and cde both as result

Comment: @Rex How? `'12309098'` does not contain `'1237'`.

Comment: I go with  Joachim Isaksson's solution.  any way thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this. But it is highly subjective to your SQL Server. For Oracle following syntax should be fine

```
SELECT * 
  FROM mydata
 WHERE groupid LIKE SUBSTR('12309098',1, LENGTH(groupid));
```

Comment: I go with  Joachim Isaksson's solution.  any way thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that input data will start with 123, then:

```
SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE groupid LIKE '123%';
```

If you are sure that input data will contain 123, then:

```
SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE groupid LIKE '%123%';
```

Comment: I found Joachim Isaksson's solution best for me.  any way thanks